# django modelform doesn't render BooleanFiled

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, modelform

I have this model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Event Title",max_length=250)
    private = models.BooleanField("Private event",default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    created   =  models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now')
```

This modelform:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    private = forms.BooleanField(label='Private event',required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = ('created',)
```

In my template the boolean field is not rendered. Even when I try to display the form with {{ form.as_p }}. 
I have droped and created the database several times. I have checked permissions. I have checked migrations. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just include `private` inside the `fields` of the `Meta` ?

Comment: Something like this: `fields = ['title', 'private', 'category']`. And remove the `exclude`.

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML?

Comment: @nik_m, how would that help?

Comment: I propose it for readibility reasons. That's all. I was about to post the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) about it. *Explicit is better than implicit*, right?

Comment: @nik_m, so your suggestion won't have any effect on the OP's problem? How is that helpful? In many cases there is nothing wrong with using `exclude` in a `ModelForm`. Very often a `ModelForm` should use all or most fields defined in the model it references. That's why `exclude` _exists_.

Comment: I just added the BooleanField. All the other fields are rendered correctly. I should mention that this is on Django 1.5 .
Also there are other fieldes to be added later, like ModelMultipleChoiceField(s) with querysets ..so it's more convenient that way.

Comment: @DanaeVogiatzi, again, could you please [edit] your question and show the generated HTML? I want to make sure this isn't just a rendering issue. (Also, you should know that Django 1.5 is _ancient_ and hasn't been supported for some time. You should really consider upgrading.)

Comment: I have checked with the inspector my html and I can assure you that it is not rendering the input filed for the checkbox! 
I know that the 1.5 is ancient but this is an app at work that need modifications so...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your forms.py add the widget as shown below:

```
private = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput, default=False)
```

This might help render the boolean field!

Comment: I did tried that as well,forgot to mention. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your model field definitions for `private` and `title` should explicitly assign the text labels to the [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) keyword argument. I would also change from `exclude` to `fields` to see what happens when you list the set of fields and stop defining `private` on the form at all.

Comment: it does blow up. When i submit the form I get an error  "Field 'private' doesn't have a default value" .How do you suggest I fix that? I fixed the other fields ,but private,since it's boolean it's supposed to have a default value. It works with other models I have.

Comment: Since when `fields` do not have a `default` argument?

Comment: @nik_m, yeah I suppose it is the [first listed argument](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L134)-- I looked at the docs instead of the code but should have realized it would have blown up in that case.

Comment: @DanaeVogiatzi blows up when? When you submit or when you try to render the form?

Comment: @Tom when i submit

Comment: @DanaeVogiatzi that seems confusing given your model definition does have a default value and your form field definition says it's not required. I would drop down to the shell (`python manage.py shell`), import your form class, create an instance and inspect the instance's `.fields` there to make sure you're seeing what you expect.

Comment: thank you @Tom ! I have solved the issue. Aparrently ,there was some hold up, I don't know what exactly,but after I droped and created the database for the 5th time ,restart the pc ,everything is working.